# React k8s ingress controller only works on path /

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, nginx, nginx-ingress

I am getting an error `You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.` when I try to access my react app using the Nginx ingress controller.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ing
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: my-service
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: tls-secret
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /my-app
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

If I change the above to use the root / it loads the app

```
...
paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

my nginx config is

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

package.json

```
...
  "homepage": ".",
```